# Return next and previous object of matching object id

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have this javascript line which returns me a matching object I search by passing an ID

```
var result = $.grep(pageResults, function(e){ return e.id == id; });
```

But I'm not interested in retrieve the matching object with the ID, what I need is to retrieve in `var result` the next object to the matching one. And of course in the same way the previous object as well.

Comment: 1.) What are the contents of `pageResults` 2.) A simple for loop will do the job.

Comment: So you want the next matched element, or the nextSibling?

Comment: we talking about jQuery selectors?

Comment: @Shiala Clearly not.

Comment: Then why not use native javascript filter function

Comment: If he is thinking what I was thinking than my answer should do

Comment: @self `pageResults` is an array of objects, what I want to do is return the object next to the matched one.

@Shiala thanks by your answer but it only returns me `{}` in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = $.grep(pageResults, function(e, i){ return (pageResults[i-1] || {}).id == id; });
```

Comment: You're welcome, for getting the previous do the same and chage the minus to a plus